# environment variable as key in yq4

Tags: shell, yaml, yq

I am using yq v4.27.2 and want to achieve this using the environment variable as the key:

```
yq -n '.key1.key2="value"'
key1:
  key2: value
```

However, I get the error as:

```
export KEY=key1.key2; yq -n '.env(KEY)="value"'
Error: 1:6: invalid input text "KEY)=env(VALUE)"
```

With this, the whole key is treated as one node,

```
export KEY="key1.key2"; yq -n '.[env(KEY)]="value"'
key1.key2: value
```

What is the right syntax? Thanks

Comment: The `yq` tags is pretty small and might not give enough information to people who want to help. Consider also using the tags `shell` and `yaml`.

Answer (score 3):

Found the syntax after reading the source code here https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/blob/master/pkg/yqlib/operator_env_test.go#L61

```
export KEY=.key1.key2; ./yq -n 'eval(strenv(KEY))="value"'
key1:
  key2: value
```

Comment: Note that the code you found is used to generate the documentation here: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#dynamically-update-a-path-from-an-environment-variable (Disclaimer: I wrote yq)